# Some questions regarding HttpWebRequest.Method "POST" in C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'll go a head and add a **short version**: How can I know which form I'm referring to, and how do I trigger it using `HttpWebRequest.Method = "POST"`?


**Thorough version**:
*Couldn't think of any great way of wording the title*
Anyways, here's my context:

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string form = "subject=Test&message=Hello world!";
    byte[] BA = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(form);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = BA.Length;
    Stream s_data = request.GetRequestStream();
    s_data.Write(BA, 0, BA.Length);
    s_data.Close();
    WebResponse res = request.GetResponse();
    s_data = res.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(s_data);
    string sr = read.ReadToEnd();
    read.Close();s_data.Close();res.Close();
    Console.WriteLine(sr);

    Console.ReadKey();
```

I got many parts of it from tutorials and such, and even though I've gotten a slight grip of how it works, there are some things that I just cannot find answers to...
My main question is, how can I get the CORRECT post values affected, and how can I actually trigger the form? I'm not sure at all whether this is correct: `string form = "subject=Test&message=Hello world!";`, but what I tried to do was to assign "Test" to `$_POST["subject]` , and "Hello" to `$_POST["message"]`. I might be way off track, so in that case, just tell me.

**Edit:** "URL" is really something else, and now when I think about it, I haven't even declared the form name...

Answer (score 0):

If you have some doubts about the values use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `urldecode`(in php) on them

```
string form = "subject="+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(subject_value)+"&message="+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message_value);
```

And on php

```
$var = isset($_POST["subject"]) ? $_POST["subject"] : null;
```

remember of add a `System.Web` reference on your project

Comment: I added `using System` and `string form = "subject=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("SubjectContent") + "&message=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("BodyContent");`, but for some reason it cannot reach "HttpUtility"... Also, will the form be triggered within the `Write` method? Not really sure where it's triggered, or if this will help that part.

Comment: The referece is `System.Web`(right click on the project, add reference) and you must using it, not just System

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I'm using `System.Web`.

Comment: Can't find it it in regedit.exe, but can't install it either (since it's a part of my OS, apparently).

Comment: HttpUtility is from the 4.5 version of the framework, check on `%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework` if there's a v4.0.30319 directory

Comment: There is. But does that mean that I need to install 4.5? Because, I've tried that, but it says I got it already.

Comment: So you don't include correctly the reference on the project, try again right click on your project -> add reference -> Assembly -> Framework -> System.Web, or upload the project and let me see

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40040/discussion-between-max-and-sam)